# SQL INTERVAL does not work on openshift

Tags: mysql, sql, openshift

I am testing table on the locanhost and Openshift I am facing the problem that on openshift I am not getting anything back when I query the data like this `WHERE arrivaltime BETWEEN curtime() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE AND curtime() + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE` although on the localhost I am getting the route 9 back. On openshift I am insert arrivaltime according to the server time. On localhost I am inserting arrivaltime according to my local time but when I change the query to this form `WHERE time_format(arrivaltime,'%H:%i')= time_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i')` I am getting something back on openshift but I need my response to be +- 2 minutes. How can I reach that without INTERVAL or can someone see the problem?

Test table:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 arrivaltime Time  NOT NULL,
 route INT(11) NOT NULL   
)
```

Inserting data:

```
INSERT INTO test(arrivaltime, route) values('11:17:00', 9)
```

This query does not work on Openshift and it works on localhost:

```
SELECT route FROM test
WHERE arrivaltime BETWEEN curtime() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE AND curtime() + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
```

Openshift curtime:

```
curtime()
11:18:57
```

when I query the `test` like this  on openshift  I am getting response but the arrivaltime should be equal to the current time.

```
SELECT route FROM test
WHERE time_format(arrivaltime,'%H:%i')= time_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i')
```

Comment: Check the actual time returned returned by `curtime()`, you might need to set the session time zone accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by a the fact that the current date/time functions in MySQL are simply confused.  They do not return `time` or `datetime` or `date` values.  Instead, they return strings or numbers:

> Returns the current time as a value in 'HH:MM:SS' or HHMMSS format,
>   depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric
>   context. The value is expressed in the current time zone.

The `-` means that the value is interpreted as a number.  To fix this, I normally use use `date_sub()`.  But you have `time` values, so you might try:

```
WHERE arrivaltime BETWEEN time(curtime()) - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE AND
                          time(curtime()) + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
```

Comment: I have tried it  with your where statement but it does not work